# Creating external table on BigQuery from an empty csv file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am getting some empty csv files on my gcs bucket on top of which I want to create external tables, I have a generic query for all the files having the filename as placeholder in my query. Here's how it looks:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `{PROJECT}.{EXTERNAL_TABLE_DATASET}.{external_table_name}`

OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://{BUCKET}/{CSV_DIR}'],
  skip_leading_rows = 1,
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 168 HOUR)
);
```

What is happening is the external tables are getting created but since the files are empty (note that they have the headers) still the table contains wrong field names like string_field_0, string_field_1

Comment: Is your CSV file really empty? Or does it contain only the header line without any row after this line?